# How to explore the symbols of a dcu files in Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, toolsapi

We know that the specification of Dcu files is a secret and it will be changed every version. Is there **ANY POSSIBLE** way to explore the symbols in a dcu file in Delphi **IDE**? (Instead of using a decompile library such as **DCU32INT** project.)

Comment: Baoquan Zuo, did you find something  ? 
As you, I don't want to decompile the DCU, if there is something in OTA that can do It, it'll be very good. I'm creating a project to replace the Delphi Uses import, and I need to know what is on interface of DCU, to make the user able to search it.

Comment: Maybe pas a module file to an api service that can retrieve the information about the file ? IOTACodeInsightManager?

Comment: IOTACodeInsightManager provides limited information about "valid" symbol list at certain position of a edit view.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an attempt using Delphi7](http://www.fatetek.net/lessons/lesson41.shtml), and there exists a [DCU32INT utility by Alexei Hmelnov](http://hmelnov.icc.ru/DCU/DCU32INT.txt).
Reverse engineering *only* the DCU might be difficult, but [inspecting the executable might help](http://delphi.about.com/od/devutilities/a/decompiling_2.htm).
Someone tried IDA, and an 'IDA Loader for Delphi/Builder 32-bit units (.DCU) by RedPlait with source' is mentioned [here](http://www.woodmann.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-4702.html), Googling it I found [this](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/13/IDA_DCU_Loader).

Comment: Thanks for the information! However, it is the last choice since the decompile is really a hack and dirty work. (Especially when support all platforms dcus are required.)